# Split an int array in a C function and return 2 different arrays

Tags: c

I try to split an int array. This array contains positive and negative numbers and I want the function to return 2 arrays one with the positive numbers and one with the negative numbers.

I already tried the following code but it doesn't work as expected.

```
 int main(void)
    {
            int array[] = {1, -1, 2, 3, 4, -5, 6};
            int cnt = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
            int *neg, *pos;
            int **low = &neg;
            int **high = &pos;

            neg = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
            pos = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

            sort(array, cnt, low, high);

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                   printf("%3d\n", pos[i]);
            }

            //same for negative array

            return 0;

    }

    int sort(int *arr, int cnt, int **low, int **high)
    {
          for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
          {
               if(arr[i] > 0)
               {
                   *high[0] = arr[i];
                   **high++;
               }
               else
               {
                   *low[0] = arr[i];
                   **low++;
               }
          }
    }
```

If someone could show me what I am doing wrong would help a lot.

Comment: I believe it should be `(*high)[0]` and `(*high)++;`

Comment: @FirstStrike What about an element with zero value in the original array?

Comment: But why use double indirection anyway? Just use single indirection.

Comment: `if(array[i] > 0)` should be `if(arr[i] > 0)`

Comment: please try to compile your code first and after that post it here.

Comment: Rather than copying values to new arrays, I suggest you simply reorder them in place so that all negative values come first. Keep a count so you know how many you have (`kneg`) and where the first non-negative value is (at `array[kneg]` (unless all values are negative)).

Comment: Continuing my previous comment: something like this --- https://ideone.com/t3xtHF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the double indirection with `int**` is unnecessary. A more suitable interface to the function is shown below.
It takes as input the array and count, and pointers to large enough output arrays. As output, the arrays are filled with the positive (negative) values, and the count for each is written to `*npos` (`*nneg`).

Treatment of zeroes is left to you. Just edit the `if` conditions.

Also note how I use `*npos += 1` instead of `(*npos)++` to avoid mistakes with operator precedence.

```
void separate(int *arr, int cnt, int *neg, int *pos, int *nneg, int *npos)
{
    *nneg = 0;
    *npos = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {
            pos[*npos] = arr[i];
            *npos += 1;
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0)
        {
            neg[*nneg] = arr[i];
            *nneg += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

While in your example you know how many positive and negative values there are, in general you should allocate arrays that are definitely large enough, i.e. `cnt` elements.